# How can I change * to italic by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change(display) `*` to `italic` style from user input textarea when button is clicked. But there is nothing working without error , I think my logic is a little wrong but can't figure anymore !!!

```js
var italic = 0;
$("#btn").click(function(){
        var val = $("#usr").val();
        val.split("").forEach(function(v,i){
            var sts = /\*/g.test(v);
            if(sts){
                if(italic == 1){
                val.substr(0, i) + '</i>' + val.substr(i + 1);
                italic = 0;
                }
                else{
                val.substr(0, i) + '<i>' + val.substr(i + 1);
                italic++;
                }
            }
        });    
        $("#display").html(val);
});
```

```css
#display {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ded;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="usr"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Insert</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: It must be only `*` or can be whole input?

Comment: You're not saving value after inserting _<i>_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple `\*(.*?)\*` to wrap output in `<i>` tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val().replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

*RegEx explained*:

`\*` - literal `*` (`*` in RegEx means any character)
`.*?` - any character
`()` - capturing group that later can be used with `$1`, `$2`... (`(.*?)` - capture any character)
`/` - RegEx delimiters (can be any character

`\*(.*?)\*` - match character `*`, than any character up till you find `*`

Comment: This one is much better, I like it.

Comment: Btw, can you explain your RegExp? I am new to it and I have to understand it more.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `val.split("")`, the `.each` loop is looping each character and it is not necessary to use RegExp to test the value, you could simply apply `v == "*"`

I would also change the data member name from `italic` to `italicTagOpened` and control the state of it by `italicTagOpened = !italicTagOpened;`

As per the above said, you are looping through each character, I would also have a data member `output` to append the result

Here is my revised function

```
var italicTagOpened = false;
$("#btn").click(function(){
  var val = $("#usr").val(),
      output = "";

  val.split("").forEach(function(v,i) {
    //var sts = /\*/g.test(v);
    if(v == "*"){
      if(italicTagOpened) output += "</i>";
      else output += "<i>";

      italicTagOpened = !italicTagOpened;
    } else output += v;
  });    
  $("#display").html(output);
});
```

You could try it on https://jsfiddle.net/uyjqerg4/1/

Answer (score -1):

```js
var italic = 0;
$("#btn").click(function(){
        var val = $("#usr").val();
        val = val.replace(/\*/g, '<i>*</i>');
        $("#display").html(val);
});
```

```css
#display {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ded;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="usr"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Insert</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

You can just use javascript replace function, its first argument can accept regex. Back slash (\) is for escaping (since * in regex has different meaning than just a *), and g stands for 'global'.

Comment: Your regex replaces `*` to `<i>*</i>` instead of wrapping content between `*`

Comment: Oops, sorry for misunderstanding his meaning